# How to learn Kali anonymously?

Tags: anonymity, security, whonix

I want to learn Kali, but wanna do this anonymously ? 
I want to register on vulnhub and learn Kali solving the CTF, but in same time I want to remain anonymous to vulnhub, in Kali and while downloading from vulnhub. 
How I can do this ? 
I was thinking about Whonix-Gateway + Whonix-Workstation.
Register a vulnhub account using Whonix-Workstation. Then install VirtualBox in Whonix-Workstation and install there Kali and the downloaded CTF from vulnhub ?
It's that possible ?